# Bond whose amortization scheme initiates at a later time in its life?

Tags: fixed-income, bond

Is there any type of bond whose amortization initiates at a later time in its life? For example the first year we observe interest-only payments and after year 1 there initiates an amortization schedule.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed there are. But they do not have a particular name.

They are mostly based on contracts specific to the counter-parties. Amortization can start in a prespecified, say, coupon payment date later than the first initial coupon payments. This also applies to drawdowns of the notional. Fully-drawn, partly-drawn etc.

I hope this helps.